# Content query web part on sharepoint online does not pull some values

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-query-web-part, xslt

I have successfully implemented the following instructions on sharepoint on premise to create a CQWP of a blog roll (a subsite)

http://erikswenson.blogspot.co.uk/2010/03/sharepoint-2010-content-query-for-blog.html

Now I am trying to get the same result on a site collection in Office365.

I am referring to the following part (leaving aside the table tags) author, numcomments and postcategory does not pull any result. I have added the new property names to the exported CQWP. Still no values at all.

```
        <table class="custom_postdetails" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"> 
        <tr> 
            <td class="custom_author"> 
                    By: <xsl:value-of select="@Author" /> | 
            </td> 
            <td class="custom_comments"> 
                    Comments: <xsl:value-of select="@NumComments" /> | 
            </td> 
            <td class="custom_category"> 
                    Category: <xsl:value-of select="@PostCategory" /> 
            </td> 
        </tr> 
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution to have those appearing as they are is to query the exact list and not the whole site collection or site, which means it is not possible to content query multiple blogs (which will have to be mandatory as subsites). At that point the number of comments is 0 or whatever and the post category do show up. I had made the Author working because I queried 'created by' instead of author.

The reason why it is as such is not known to me, feel free to comment.